# Describe the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $|z-i| = 2|z+i|$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

My approach was to set $z=x+iy$ and the solve. I got down to

$$ |-x| + |-i(y-1)| = 0, \qquad x = i(y-1) $$

Is this the right approach?? It just doesn't seem right and I'm not really sure how to interpret my answer. Please tell me the correct way to do this.

---

Hello, thank you for your responses. 
Here are my steps now: 
$$ |z-i| = 2|z+i| $$
$$ |x + iy -i| = 2|x + iy +i| $$
$$ |x + i(y -1)| = 2|x + i(y+1)| $$
$$ x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 2(x^2 + (y+1)^2) $$
$$ x^2 + (y^2 -2y +1) = 2(x^2 + (y^2 + 2y + 1)) $$
$$ x^2 + y^2 -2y +1 = 2x^2 + 2y^2 + 4y + 2 $$
$$ x^2 + y^2 + 6y + 1 = 0 $$
Equation of a circle is:
$$ (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2 $$
Complete the square to get: 
$$ x^2 + (y+3)^2 = 8 $$
So it is a circle centered at (0,-3) with radius 2sqrt(2).

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I am not sure how you arrived that expression. Notice, for instance, that $$|z-i| = |x+(y-1)i| = \sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}.$$ It would be also interesting to give a look on [*circle of Apollonius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius), as this provide an alternative way of describing the locus of $z$'s satisfying $|z-i| = 2|z+i|$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius

Answer (score 1):

Just a little correction:

$$|x+iy-i|=2|x+iy+i|$$ $$or, x^2+(y-1)^2=4\{x^2+(y+1)^2\}$$ $$or, x^2+y^2-2y+1=4x^2+4y^2+8y+4$$ $$or, 3x^2+3y^2+10y+3=0$$
Which is the equation of a circle.

[image]

Comment: How did the 2 turn into a 4? First to second line? Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: @windfallisland The || sign describes the magnitude of that quantity. Hence here you have $$|A|=2|x+(y+1)i|$$ or $${|A|}^2=(2\sqrt{x^2 +(y+1)^2})^2$$

Comment: I agree with the comment and $|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$